# MATH_REAL log2 function

Tags: vhdl

Log2 function of MATH_REAL is not working.

Here is the code:

```
Num: integer:=64;
num: integer:=2;    
...
out: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(natural(log2(Num/(2**(num*2-1)))) downto 0)
...
```

The error I am having is: "found '0' definitions of operator "/", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "/""

Thanks!

Comment: What you type does not come close to valid code. There are too many things broken in this. Please provide a small, but complete snippet of code that compiles and gives only the error you want to discuss.

Answer (score 3):

Cast as `real` before you apply `log2` (or before you divide, if you don't want integer division).

Incidentally, you can't use "`Num`" and "`num`" for two different identifiers - VHDL is not case-sensitive.

```
std_logic_vector(natural(log2(real(num1) / real(2**(num2*2-1)))) downto 0);
```

Comment: `out` cannot be used as a signal or variable name either, it's a reserved word.  The questioner's error message implies there was a log2 function found.  Your answer analyzes which tells us log2 in package real_math is acceptable.  Now the scary question is why?  Is there geometry implied by the expression for finding the left bound?

Comment: I don't see any reason log2 should be invalid or ambiguous here - I'm probably misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 1):

Log2 has the following signature (see: [here](https://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076.2-1996/math_real.vhdl)) :

```
function LOG2 (X : in REAL ) return REAL;
```

you are giving it

```
Num/(2**(num*2-1))
```

which is probably of type integer, ie not the real type expected, assuming you are using standard division for integers. My suggestion is you look into how to divide reals (e.g. through casting, though this may cause synthesis issues), or overload the division operator yourself.